# How to get JQuery from getbootstrap website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

What is the way to include JQuery from their website - 'getbootstrap.com'?

This screenshot shows an older version of that site perhaps.
Perhaps of 4.6 version: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/

What would be the way to access JQuery from the latest version?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/

I can't find the JQuery script link there. Please guide.

[image]

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/#cdn-via-jsdelivr

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"How does website X work"_ is not one of those topics.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, but if the code directly depends on getting something from that particular website, then you may suggest how to better frame the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 [removed the dependency on jQuery](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2021/05/05/bootstrap-5/#javascript).

You don't need jQuery to use Bootstrap any more, and Bootstrap no longer provides instructions on including it (because there's no need).

If you want to write your own code that uses jQuery, then follow the instructions on [jQuery's website](https://jquery.com/). (Note, however, that there isn't very much left in jQuery that isn't just as easy to do with native DOM and Web APIs).

Note that the instructions for Bootstrap 4 told you to get jQuery from jQuery's website too. Bootstrap have never hosted jQuery for their users.